# How to modify external SQL query string from native query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an external connection in BigQuery with another data base
When I call something from external query I have to use function
`EXTERNAL_QUERY("atdv3.eu.tracker", '''SELECT stage, site_id, clicks, cost, p_leads_v2, revenue_tb, leads_tb FROM tracker t WHERE t.source_id = SOME_NATIVE_BQ_TABLE.source_id ''')`
Second parameter is string and I need to modify it using native BQ SQL.
How can I make it?

Comment: not clear what is your use case and what exactly you are asking  - you might want to rephrase / clarify and provide more details so we will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use external connection as a table and join with BigQuery table.

**Example:**

```
SELECT
  mysql.*
FROM
  EXTERNAL_QUERY("Connection-name", "SELECT * FROM mysql_table;") mysql,
  bqdataset.bqtable bq
WHERE
  mysql.source_id = bq.source_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Of course I know this way. But I don't want read full table. I need only 5% of rows (~300000 row)